# How do I get the iframe that opened a window in JavaScript from Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe that opens a new webpage.

In that webpage, I want to access a function on the window of the iframe.

I try to call `window.opener.myFunction()`, but the opener is the `<iframe>`'s **parent** window, and not the `<iframe>`'s window.

Because of the dynamic nature of the page, I don't want to explicitly get the contentWindow of the `<iframe>` from the parent window. Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: Good workaround, if possible, don't use an iframe.

Comment: "but the opener is the `<iframe>`'s parent window" How have you detected this? `opener` surely refers to the `window` within `iframe`, if that window was opened from the `iframe`. I'm quite sure there's something else going on.

Comment: are the domains on all three pages the same?

Comment: I tried doing this myself and it worked just fine on IE 11. Any specific version this is happening?

Comment: @dandavis, All on the same domain. I looked it closer, and it turns out the iframe is within another iframe, and the opener on the opened window is referencing the iframe's parent iframe :(

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `<iframe>`'s id, you could use getElementById().

For example:

The first webpage would have:

```
<iframe id="launcher"></iframe>
```

And the launched page could use:

```
window.opener.getElementById("launcher").myFunction();
```

Comment: `iframe` elements don't have JavaScript ; ).

Comment: I'm afraid I can't get around using an iframe since this is built in Microsoft Dynamics CRM :(